# Добавление полей и бд

Tags: php, база-данных, sql

Есть таблица, а в нет поля:

```
id
nazvanie
data
```

Хочу сделать форму html с этими полями и чтобы можно было добавлять самому до 10 полей.
Получается, у каждого поля будет name с id, например:

```
<input type="text" name="nazvanie_1" value="">
<input type="text" name="date_1" value="">

<input type="text" name="nazvanie_2" value="">
<input type="text" name="date_2" value="">

<input type="text" name="nazvanie_3" value="">
<input type="text" name="date_3" value="">
```

и так далее. Post запросом принимаем данные и записываем в бд. Так вот, как можно это организовать? Именно добавление в бд.
Дело в том, что получается, при добавлении двух или более записей последняя перезаписывает предыдущие при добавлении.

Comment: Можно, и название этому есть давно phpMyAdmin

Comment: Gedweb, не хотите отвечать промолчите и пройдите мимо. нечего острить

Comment: > дело в том, что получается при добавлении двух или более записей последняя перезаписывает предыдущие при добавлении.

Такого не бывает. Вы либо сами стираете записи, либо обновляете существующие.

Comment: @bobiq, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="nazvanie_1" value="">
<input type="text" name="date_1" value="">
```

Костыли какие-то! Чем Вас не устраивает

```
<input type="text" name="nazvanie[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="date[]"     value="">
<input type="text" name="nazvanie[]" value="">
<input type="text" name="date[]"     value="">
```

или еще лучше:

```
<input type="text" name="data[0][nazvanie]" value="">
<input type="text" name="data[0][date]"     value="">
<input type="text" name="data[0][nazvanie]" value="">
<input type="text" name="data[0][date]"     value="">
```

Обработчик второго примера будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
<?php
// какая-то логика

// Получаем данные из формы (массив ассоциативных массивов)
$data = $_POST['data'];
// проходимся по $data и собираем sql запросы
foreach($data as $record)
{
    $title = mysql_escape_string($record['nazvanie']);
    $date  = mysql_escape_string($record['date']);
    $sql   = 'INSERT INTO `table` (`nazvanie`, `date`) 
              VALUES ("'.$title.'", "'$date'")';
    // отправляете запрос в бд
}
```

Замечу, что поле id в бд у Вас должно быть `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

P.S. `mysql_escape_string` - устарела и приведена в качестве примера "очистки" данных от всякого трэша, опасного для БД.